# Redirecting every page in Apache after a certain segment?

Tags: apache, redirect

Right now in my .conf file, I've got a page redirecting to /zzzzz/ like so:

```
RewriteRule ^/*xxxx/yyyyyyyy/*$ /zzzzz/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

How can I configure it so any subdirectory after /yyyyyyyy/ will redirect to /zzzzz/, without pointing them individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

`RewriteRule ^/*xxxx/yyyyyyyy/(.*)$ /zzzzz/$1 [L,R=301,NC]`